# C: Image read and stored inside char array containing zero's

Tags: c

I'm currently developing an HTTP web-server in C, which is already able to respond with .html and .css files. Therefore I read from the files with fread and store the content inside a char array.

```
char *body_pointer = malloc(fsize + 1); //fsize being my files size
//checking content_type of file, but for opening images as binary.

if (!strcmp(content_type, "image/jpeg") || !strcmp(content_type, "image/png") ) {
  strcpy(open_as, "rb");
} else {
  strcpy(open_as, "r");
}

FILE *fp = fopen(path, open_as);

if (fp != NULL) {
  do {
    bytes = fread(body_pointer, 1, chunk, fp);
    body_pointer += bytes;
  } while (bytes == chunk);
  fclose(fp);
  *body_pointer = '\0';
}
```

I then add the files content to the header string with strcat:

```
strcat(response_pointer, body_start_pointer); //response_pointer is the pointer to the array already holding the header.
```

I then loop thorough the response_pointer, store the content in an array and send my response:

```
write(new_socket, response, strlen(response)); //response is the array holding the response, new_socket is the socket.
```

As is said, everything works fine doing it with .html and .css files, but ive got a problem with .pgn and .jpg's.

I debugged the program and found out, that the image binary contains zeros. Since I'm storing it in a char array (pointed to by a char pointer), the zero is interpreted as end of the string. How do I go about it? can i just delete the zeros? Is the image gonna be manipulated then? Do I have to create a new array. storing everything inside it except the zero's?

Comment: Don't use `strcpy()` if your data contains zeros that do not mark the end of a string. Use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: ... and `strlen`... *and* what if you need to serve HTML files that are in UTF-16 encoding, say...

Comment: Unrelated: If you make `open_as` a `const char *` you can drop the copying and assign the string literal directly to `open_as`.

Comment: Having a special case treating "image/jpeg" and "image/png" as binary and everything else as text is asking for trouble, as is the use of null-terminated string handling routines. Better to treat everything as binary files (open with "rb") and avoid `strlen`, `strcpy`, `strcat` etc. Just keep track of the number of bytes written to the response buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your string of bytes is not null-terminated (it is not a C-style string).

You should replace the `strcat` by `memcpy`, as follows:

```
memcpy(response_pointer, body_start_pointer, fsize);
```

And you should replace the `strlen()` by the real length:

```
write(new_socket, response, fsize);
```

Besides, the following line is useless and should be removed (as there is no need for null-termination):

```
*body_pointer = '\0';
```